# Replace occurrences of string pattern

Tags: ios, string, swift

So this is a string I get back from the server:

```
var arrayString = "IT34:1, IT35:2, IT36:1, IT35:3"
```

I want to get rid of any occurrences of ":1", ":2" and am using:

```
let cleanStr = arrayString.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString(":1", withString: "", options: NSStringCompareOptions.LiteralSearch, range: nil)

let cleanStr1 = cleanStr.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString(":2", withString: "", options: NSStringCompareOptions.LiteralSearch, range: nil)
```

And so on...

Which doesn't seem very efficient.  Is it possible to accomplish this with just one `.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString` method?  Like occurrences of ":(a number)"?

Comment: I can understand why you want only one of those, it's a long method name to type!

Comment: I'm going to guess there is a RegEx way of doing this quite cleanly.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This can be done using regular expressions:

```
let string = "IT34:1, IT35:2, IT36:1, IT35:3"
var cleanStr = string
if let regex = NSRegularExpression(pattern: ":[0-9]", options:.CaseInsensitive, error: nil) {
    cleanStr = regex.stringByReplacingMatchesInString(string, options: nil, range: NSMakeRange(0, countElements(string)), withTemplate: "")
}
println(cleanStr)
```

---

And in Objective-C:

```
NSString *string = @"IT34:1, IT35:2, IT36:1, IT35:3";
NSRegularExpression *regex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:@":[0-9]" options:NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive error:nil];
NSString *newString = [regex stringByReplacingMatchesInString:string options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, [string length]) withTemplate:@""];
NSLog(@"%@", newString);
```

Comment: Yayyy.  was in the middle of translating your original obj c answer to swift but you beat me to it.  thanks!

Comment: I was going to suggest regex, but this is a really clear, complete answer. (In both Swift and Objective-C no less!) well done. One gotcha. Apparently in Swift 1.2 `countElements` has been renamed as `count`, so that bit will have to change if you're using Xcode 6.3 or later.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know the exact pattern of those ":1" thingies, but here's a solution you might fiddle with:

```
let cleanStr = ", ".join(arrayString.componentsSeparatedByString(", ").map { ($0 as NSString).substringToIndex(4) })
```

This solution will work as long as the ':1" things have one digit.

Here's a general solution:

```
let cleanStr = ", ".join(arrayString.componentsSeparatedByString(", ").map {
    ($0 as NSString).componentsSeparatedByString(":")[0] as String
})
```

Comment: I *think* this will be drastically inefficient compared to the regex approach, but I'm not 100% certain.  Would be interesting to test.

Comment: @nhgrif Please know that you can now be 100% certain! I did a rough benchmark and the regex solution seems to be 10x faster. Thanks for the idea.